# 404 Custom Error in IIS 6.0 and ASPX doesnt work

Tags: .net, iis, http-status-code-404, asp.net

I've created a 404 error page called 404.aspx which works fantastic when I call it manually.
But after setting the "custom error" in web.config and IIS 6.0. It doesn't work properly.

for example, If I type the URL the wrong way, it won't work and a message like the one below, appears.

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: **http://domain/anything** (without an extension)
Line Number 1, Column 2:<%@ page language="C#" masterpagefile="~/Public.master" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="_404, App_We
```

And, if I type the url like this: **http://domain/anything.ASPX (ADDING THE .ASPX)** at the end, it will redirect to the custom error 404.aspx correctly and works fine.

What can I do to make this work ?

Comment: Could it be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704561/custom-error-pages-in-iis-6-0-using-aspx-pages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you've set the IIS custom error page type to `File` instead of `Url`.

Setting to `File` will just cause IIS to render the contents of your error page verbatim to the response stream (i.e. as a static file) instead of doing a HTTP redirect to the error page causing the page to be processed by ASP.NET.

IIS 6 requires that an 'Absolute URL within the site' to be entered if using the URL message type, for example:

`/404.aspx`

Comment: that was the firs option I tried. But whatever I write, a yellow callout appears with the following message : Wrong URL Format. Please enter an absolute URL within the site.

Comment: IfI type anything in the url without the .aspx extension, it will show an error message, and if i type any page name and add the .aspx extension, it will come with the nice error page. weird thing. don't know what else to do.

Comment: Kev. You were right. you solved the issue. This is the accepted answer. I was using "~/404.aspx".

Comment: +1 ~ I was using "file" and it worked in IE9, but not FF5. When I changed it to url it started working in FF.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your syntax is as follows:

```
<customErrors
       mode="RemoteOnly" 
       defaultRedirect="~/errors/GeneralError.aspx" 
/>
```

To see the custom page yourself set mode to "On"

```
<customErrors
       mode="On" 
       defaultRedirect="~/errors/GeneralError.aspx" 
/>
```

The modes are defined as follows:

- On – error details are not shown to anybody, even local users. If you specified a custom error page it will be always used.
- Off – everyone will see error details, both local and remote users. If you specified a custom error page it will NOT be used.
- RemoteOnly – local users will see detailed error pages with a stack trace and compilation details, while remote users with be presented with a concise page notifying them that an error occurred. If a custom error page is available, it will be shown to the remote users only.

Comment: I have this in my web.config                                  <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/404.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>

Comment: thanks, i modified my webconfig quickly. I added this:     <customErrors mode="On" 
defaultRedirect="~/404.aspx"> 
</customErrors>                                                            But it's pretty much the same. :/

Comment: @UXdesigner - I hope you edited the existing customErrors setting, and didn't add a second.

Comment: It is the existing one, didn't add a second.